# Working with Coopers Australian Pale Ale kit

Tags: kits

One of my friends bought me two cans of Coopers Australian Pale Ale. I haven't used kits before and I am having trouble figuring out what's inside. So far what I can deduce it's a combination of hop extracts and some type of sugar extract?

What I want to know is the exact sugar content and get some opinions on the following:

- They use some basic hop extracts, based on some research it's not desirable to boil the content. So what I wanted to do is a 10 minute boil of some nice hops for flavour, letting it coold down a bit before dumping in the contents of the kit (I was thinking a combination of Amarillo and Citra). Would this work?
- I have no idea what the level of sugar is and how much the OG will be for a single gallon of beer. If anyone has some idea on this then I can also consider buying more fermentables to increase the OG.
- Can I trust the yeast packet provided with this kit (it's been in my cupboard for 8 months already). Or should I just get some Safale S05 instead?

Comment: Isn't there a manual inside the kits?

Comment: Did you already brew all-grain?

Comment: Yes and yes, havent opened the can yet :)

Answer (score 1):

I have posted some tips [here](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/21671/adding-ingredients-to-an-ipa-kit/21675#21675) already.

But to answer specifically the question:

1. You can do a 10 min boil.  Dry hop is another option.
2. Yes, you may add dry malt extract or dextrose to increase alcohol content.
3. If the yeast is old, you should make a starter.  If you have problems with the starter, you should get fresh yeast.  I made the mistake of using the cooper's yeast that was over a year old without a starter, it was just not strong enough to start fermenting properly.

Comment: No, don't boil it!  You'll just needlessly drive off some hop aroma.  But yes, adding some DME is a good idea.

Comment: But if the purpose of the boil is to add new hops,  it will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the cans are fresh. Old malt extract has an oxidized off flavor that tastes like sherry. From experience I can say a 3 year old can of Coopers extract is long enough. :/